# Django site framework: How to manage access to different sites sharing same database?

Tags: django

I have two Django sites that share the same database and some functionnalities. Each site has its own settings.py with a different SITE_ID. Each site is running under its own runserver process.

I have this custom backend that check if user is allowed to access the current site during login:

```
user_or_none = super(SiteBackend, self).authenticate(**credentials)
if user_or_none and user_or_none.get_profile().sites.filter(id=Site.objects.get_current().id).count() < 1:
    user_or_none = None
```

A user can access a site if SITE_ID is stored in his profile (in auth_user_profile_site table)

My problem is that when a user is logged in one of the site he has access, he can then switch to the other site that he does not have access and system let him enter.

Also, once logged in one site, It seems that when switching to the other site, SITE_ID obtained from: `Site.objects.get_current().id` does not corespond to this second site ID, we always receive the SITE_ID from the first site logged in...

Is it normal behaviour of the site framework?

Any suggestion how to solve those problems?

Thanks a lot

Etienne

Answer (score 0):

You should look for answers in django session framework. When someone logins it saves user id in session. And session is just a temporary storage (you can acces it in view `request.session`).  Depend on session backend,  it can interact with that other site.

Look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.login)

Comment: The session middleware is already enable... Do I have to do something particular regarding sessions to get correct SITE_ID? Why does get_current_site(request) seems to get stick to first logged in site id?